# Unity: How can I run Unity builds created in High Sierra & Verify they run on Mojave without a Mojave computer?

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, mojave, mac-appstore

I have Unity 2020.3.0f1 Mac apps that were created on end-of-life High Sierra computers. I recently purchased a Mac Mini M1 computer. The apps run on both computers. I have to execute a terminal command on them to get them to open on the M1 computer.

Apple changed the App Store Upload process so that now we have to notarize that new apps will run on Mojave. I don't have a computer that runs Mojave. From my understanding you can't test Unity builds using the Apple Simulators. Is there another option to test my apps to see if they will run on Mojave?

Comment: You an run macos in a virtual machine. If I w a s making money from writing a pps I would have a vm of each version you say you support. That migh ht mean getting a newer Intel m a c to run big sur

Comment: This is the first time since I've owned computers that reached end of life. I'm distributing Mac apps outside the Mac App Store and have to verify that they run on Mojave. I'm creating virtual machines for Mojave and Catalina on my Windows PC using VirtualBox.

Comment: Your computer has not reached end of life you can still run eve rything you could on it. You just can't run new things on it

Comment: Note that the Apple EULA says you cannot run macOS on a non Apple computer. Also as you are doing this for profit the cost of an old machine (eg mac mini) that can run Mojave is not that much and should easily be covered in your business plan.

Comment: I have to say, I would be exceedingly surprised if an app worked on both High Sierra and Big Sur (I assume the M1 Mac Mini can run Big Sur) but not Mojave and Catalina. Especially a Unity game, which does very little with AppKit or other Apple-specific frameworks. Frankly, assuming you're a one-person operation, I think you could get away with not testing it. Testing is always good, but you'll never be able to test every possible hardware configuration—every point release, every Mac GPU, etc., unless you're the size of Google or Adobe.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy you read my mind. We are a two-person operation. Our Unity apps that were built as Intel 64-bit work on both High Sierra and Big Sur. We have made the assumption they will work with Mojave & Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is tagged with Catalina too, GitHub has machines where a build can be tested.

Just write some automated tests that run using the binary (which you might want to upload to git-lfs) and use GitHub actions to run them remotely.

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions
- https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files

There are plenty of workflow files available if you search properly. https://github.com/search/advanced

There might be other such CI/CD delivery options too with other macOS versions.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software